# Cypress failed to start. This may be due to a missing library or dependency (M1 mac)

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

I just got my M1 and trying to get my head around cypress so basically following basic steps in order to open cypress and check if its there and its possible to run it.

1. mkdir cypress_test
2. npm init -i
3. npm install --save-dev cypress
4. npx cypress open (thats where issues appears)

   Cypress failed to start.

   This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

   Please refer to the error below for more details.

   ---

   Command failed with Unknown system error -86: /Users/test/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.6.1/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress --no-sandbox --smoke-test --ping=610
   spawn Unknown system error -86

I have attempted trying to install cypress with force with the following command -
npx cypress install --force however sadly it did not help and same error appears

I also saw somebody manage to fix it by changing Mac with M1 chip to OS ver. 11.5.x (BigSur) however is not something i would like to do.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem
At the moment, Cypress cannot be compiled under the ARM-based architecture of new Mac computers and Continuous Integration (CI) providers do not currently offer M1 instances. For these reasons, Cypress is not currently released for the ARM-based architectures and will require Intel emulation for some time.

Therefore, running npm install cypress will install the Intel-based package until these challenges are resolved. See here for workaround

See here for more info https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/01/20/running-cypress-on-the-apple-m1-silicon-arm-architecture-using-rosetta-2/

Comment: yep figure it out already and a single command installing Rosetta 2 helped

Answer (score 1):

The only way that i managed to sort this out is by install Rosetta 2 that transitions between Intel and Apple processors.

softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/01/20/running-cypress-on-the-apple-m1-silicon-arm-architecture-using-rosetta-2/